# Mobile 3D Game Performance Auto detection at start time

Tags: android, 3d, performance-testing, unreal-engine4

I'm developing 3d game using Unreal engine3 for android device.

It try to detect device's 3d game performance at start time using

"GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS", "GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS" factor.

```
if (MaxFragmentUniformVectors < 256) then LowPerformancePhone

else if (MaxFragmentUniformVectors < 512 || MaxVertexUniformVectors < 256) then MidPerformancePhone
```

and so on.

But, I think it is some what weird performance factor.

According to it's factor then Galaxy S5 is Low Performance Phone.

GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 256
GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS : 224

(http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gles_generatereport.php?reportID=198)

Would you recommend some general way detect performance?

Or Am I have wrong understanding on mobile performance?